# Achieving C++ template behaviour without having templates available

Tags: c++, templates, embedded

Is it possible to (simply) achieve C++ template behaviour without having templates available? I'm using an embedded C++ toolchain that does not have that feature, but it would certainly be useful if I could replicate it.

As a usage example, I'd like to create a number of circular buffers for different types. At the moment, I have only a `uint8_t` circular buffer but I need more.

Comment: Templates are a whole programming language, so no. But you might be able to replicate *some* functionality with macros, code generation scripts, or `constexpr`, although I doubt your embedded toolchain supports the latter.

Comment: The closest you can get is some preprocessor macro trickery IMHO, but nothing with compatible syntax. Another option might be to use a c++ frontend to generate c intermediary code.

Comment: Hmmm, no, I don't have the latter features.

Comment: I'd like to avoid macro trickery that destroys the maintainability of the code, which it feels like this would in this case?

Comment: What specific behavior/functionality do you need?  "Templates" covers a lot of ground.  Even suggestions about macro/preprocessor trickery are kind of flying blind without some indication of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @EdKing I'm not sure, but having a look at clang might offer some options.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down to what problem you are solving and what tools you have available. Perhaps mention what the hardware platform is; perhaps a more complete C++ implementation exists.

Comment: @frasnian An example of something that I want to create: circular buffers that can handle, say, a uint8_t and a float?

Comment: You could use the token-pasting preprocessor operator (`##`), but you'd have to specify the type when calling (no type deduction would be possible in a preprocessor macro).  Something like `#define CircBuf(T, size)   CircBuf_impl_##T(size)`, call as `CircBuf(uint8_t, size)`  You'd also have to wrap the definitions for the (generic) implementation class in preprocessor macros.

Comment: @frasnian I see what you're doing, but that seems like it's going to be a nightmare for maintenance. Also, that doesn't stop me having to rewrite each implementation?

Comment: May be too long for a comment, so have to add as an answer.

Comment: @EdKing You'd make the class implementation a macro too. Yes, templates are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't have to rewrite it for each implementation, just wrap the actual definitions in macros:

```
#define GenerateCircBufClass(T)\
class CircBuf_impl_##T \
{\
public: \
  CircBuf_impl_##T(); \
  ~CircBuf_impl_##T(); \
  // etc...
};

GenerateCircBufClass(uint8_t)
GenerateCircBufClass(float)
// etc...
```

Comment: This all seems rather interesting. Thanks, I will give it a try!

Comment: I'm guessing I'd lose the ability to debug this, as I'd have to completely define the implementation in the preprocessor?

Comment: @EdKing Compilers usually give you the means to obtain the output of a pre-processing run (see the `-S` flag in gcc for example). So you could generate real C++ source files like this if needed, then compile them.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  I'd approach it by first creating a complete, well-debugged version for a single type, then making it generic.  But, yeah, debugging preprocessor-generated stuff is never fun.

Comment: I suppose that would be the (quite large) concession then. Thanks for the suggestion for the generation using the preprocessing output @juanchopanza, but this is too much faffery for me!